# adding numbers in a csv file without csv module using python

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to not use the `csv` module as my teacher is, I think, making a point of how to use this simple maybe older methods of iteration. I know he type casted or changed something int in order to add a csv files total. The syntax for the file is (name("string"),grade(int)) as a csv. Here is one line of the csv file:
`Andrew,69,52,32,83,22,33,77,34`
It is comma delimited of course. I have been able to get it to print out the numbers only without headers, but I am missing something to be able to add the grades up. The error im getting now is this:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

The code I have now is :

```
f = open("lab0604.csv","r+")     
f.readline()
    for line in f:
         x = line.split(",")
         for i in x:`
             print(sum(i[2:]))
```

Any thoughts on how to figure this out would be appreciated. I am still new to the format rules with SO so I know my indent is a bit off but I know its not the indent. Thanks for helping. I am thinking it is just a cast to int im missing in the right place. Thanks again for any help I may receive.

Comment: Now I remember , he wanted to prove these problem could be completed with one line statements.

Comment: Do this - `print(sum(int(i[2:]))`

Comment: seems to be the right idea, but now im getting an error of 
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'drew'

Comment: Thats because in your csv file, there is a string

Comment: How can you add a name or words to a string

Comment: Look at my answer, you will get desired output

Comment: I believe using append will help me get ?

Comment: Append will append it to a list, you don't need that. What you need to do is filter out the names and add the integers

Answer (score 1):

A better approach -

```
f = open("lab0604.csv","r+")     
f.readline()
    for line in f:
         x = line.split(",")
         for i in x:`
             grades = 0
             for i in mylist:
                 if type(i) == type(0):
                    grades = i + grades
        
             print(grades)
```

List Comprehension (One-liner or almost one-line)-

```
for i in x:
    a = [b for b in mylist if type(b) == type(0)]
    print(sum(a))
```

Comment: Thanks I will put this in my editor to study, I appreciate the help !

Comment: I know this is lengthy but it is more simple. You can however use [`List Comprehensions`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), to make it a one-liner.

Comment: What makes it a better approach, comparing the types?

Comment: I feel it is better because it shows each step without any complications. However, you are free to use your own techniques like `sum` etc...

Comment: Im still learning, but this class has been totally worth it. I get stuck on fundamentals and sometimes you are just tired of reading code or not figuring out when you know it is simple. Thanks again for your help it really helped me finish this assignment!

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("lab0604.csv", "r+")
f.readline()
for line in f:
    x = line.split(",")
    print(sum(int(number) for number in x[1:])) # the first element`s index is 0
```

Comment: If the name is not in the first index (but it is), this will not work as intended. But, this would work assuming they follow the index